Is it possible to find and transfer drivers from one pc to another?
I have PC1 and PC2. PC1 recognizes my Redmi 9A android but PC2 doesnt. PC2 recognizes my Bello2 android but PC1 doesnt. Can I search somehow which drivers/infs/files allow this recognition and transfer them between PCs, so that both are recognized?
Both PCs are the same win7 installation.
Searching and setting up redmi 9A drivers from the web took me several weeks. I dont want to waste so much time again,since I have a PC that already recognizes Bello2 I would like to just copy the files. Downloading LG drivers for the Bello2 didnt work, its still "unknown device" in devmngr.

what do you mean by "recognized"? what could have taken you several weeks to do that you could just copy from one system to another?

Finding drivers for the redmi,online, and making them work.

Is it possible, yes, but only if you already know the .inf for the driver you want to export. Much easier to simply download and install the driver.

@Ramhound Can you elaborate?

@theo1996 - Since you don’t know what .inf the driver is it will be difficult to run the proper commands, but as the other answer indicates, only the newer versions of DISM support exporting the driver anyway

Some third-party driver packages can be extracted from a Windows installation. I can explain how to extract them, but I do not know if the ones you want will be included.
I tested this answer using 64 bit Windows 7 with SP1.
The command to use is Dism. Unfortunately, the Dism command included with Windows 7 does not have the required option. However, the Dism from Windows 10 does.
Instead of downloading directly to my Windows 7 machine, I used another machine to download and then transferred to a shared folder on my Windows 7 machine. I downloaded and transferred the following files.

The file Win11_22H2_English_x64v1.iso, which a 64 bit Windows 10 installation file downloaded from Microsoft.
The file WinCDEmu-4.1.exe, which installs software which allows Window 7 to mount ISO files. This software is by SysProgs. There are many others which could have been chosen instead.

There are other ways to get these files. You could use a flash drive or a web browser that still works with your Windows 7.
I installed WinCDEmu, then mounted the ISO file as drive V:. Next, I opened a Command Prompt window as an Administrator and entered the following commands to extract the driver packages.
cd /d %userprofile%\desktop
md drv
v:\sources\dism /online /export-driver /destination:drv


One command for installing drivers is pnputil. I would recommend creating a Restore Point before installing any drivers. Usage for pnputil can be found by enter the command without any parameters.

Using Dism++
I downloaded and transferred Dism++ 10.1.1002.1 from the Major Geeks website. This does run on Windows 7 SP1. Below is an image.

I was able to extract driver packages. I did not compare with what Dism extracted.

References

DISM Driver Servicing (.inf) Command-Line Options
Installing a driver (.inf) file from command line
PnPUtil Command Syntax
Export-WindowsDriver


Thanks I will try it. Am I supposed to download the DIsm W10 version and use it on win 7?

I found Dism++, will that work? I opened it and found a option to list all drivers,export and add. Seems faster than downloading win11 dism version

@theo1996 - DISM++ only work on Windows 10+

@Ramhound: How did you come to your conclusion Dism++ only works on Windows 10+. It seems to work with respect to extracting drivers where Windows 7 SP1 is running. Am I missing something?

theo1996: I used the Dism that comes with the Windows 10 installation ISO file. I downloaded this ISO from Microsoft. Also, I updated my answer with respect to using Dism++.

@DavidAnderson - It most certainly based on DISM from Windows 10. I am familiar with the project. I suppose I never thought something that requires DISM from Windows 10+ would run on Windows 7
